# Напешите как правильно создавать регистрацию и авторизацию

Tags: html, css, python, django

Уже который день не могу создать Регистрацию и авторизацию как это сделать блин помогите плиз .
Создал что то выходило а потом просто данные с форм не добавлялися в базу данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Регистрация:**

*forms.py:*

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].strip()
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Пользователь с таким email уже существует')

        return email
```

*views.py:*

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate


@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        context = {'form': form,
                   'username': username,
                   'password1': password1,
                   'password2': password2,
                   'email': email}

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password1)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

*register.html:*

```html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username }}">
  <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ email }}">
  <input type="password" name="password1" value="{{ password1 }}">
  <input type="password" name="password2" value="{{ password2 }}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Данный пример делает следующее:
 1. Когда приходит POST запрос, проверяет данные, в том числе уникальность email.
 2. Если данные верны, регистрирует и логинит пользователя, иначе отправляет форму с данными назад.

**Авторизация:**

*urls.py:*

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
...


urlpatterns = [
    path(r'login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html'), name='login'),
    ...
]
```

*login.html:*

```py
...
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
...
```

*Примечание: данный код очень далёк от идеала, это учебный пример. После понятия принципа, рекомендую Вам переписать его. Как минимум, советую использовать представления на основе классов ([CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/)) и [формы Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/).*